# How to convert a ndarray into opencv::Mat using Boost.Python?

Tags: python-3.x, c++11, boost-python, mat, numpy-ndarray

I am reading an image in Python and passing that numpy array to C++ using Boost.Python and receiving that in `ndarray`.

I need to convert the same into `cv::Mat` to perform operations in OpenCV C++.

How do I do that?

Comment: this might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736593/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-ndarray-into-cvmat, https://github.com/yati-sagade/opencv-ndarray-conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for that from the documentations:

We Have to receive the numpy array as `numeric::array` in C++ and have to do the following steps to easily convert the numpy into `cv::mat` efficiently.

```
void* img_arr = PyArray_DATA((PyObject*)arr.ptr());
```

And we need to pass this void ptr to the cv::Mat Constructor with other parameters required.

```
Mat image(rows, cols , CV_8UC3, img_arr);
```

1. int parameter: Expects the no. of rows
2. int parameter: Expects the no. of cols
3. Type parameter : Expects the type of image.
4. Void Pointer Parameter: Expects the image data.

And this resolves the problem!!!!.